# Replacing either the light socket or the whole recessed light fixture

Tags: kitchens, recessed-lighting

[image][image]
Fixing my old house up to put on the market.  Had it rewired a couple yrs ago. This light fixture is above my kitchen sink.Keeps tripping out when turned on.  I can't find square recessed lighting to save my life! Can I just have the socket replaced or do I need a new light fixture all together?  Obviously not a square recessed one. I would like to update the look of the light if possible without putting too much money or work into it.

Comment: What makes you think the socket is shorting and tripping the breaker? It could be at the switch or elsewhere. That said, were it my home I'd be removing that nasty old thing and installing an inexpensive new fixture over the hole. You won't spend much more than you would for a socket, and the result would be an aesthetic improvement to be sure.

Comment: Have you talked to a proper lighting supply company?  Most people go straight to the big-box stores, get no useful help, and give up.

Comment: Whenever I turn it on, the GFCI outlet trips out. I didn't have issues with the light till my house was rewired. I didn't have GFCI outlets before either. I would love to remove  it but I don't know how to go about doing that without professional help. lol I don't even know the proper term for this particular socket. I've searched online and not getting any results.

Comment: Replacing the fixture is easier than adding a ceiling fan, my concern would be the GFCI tripping it may not be the fixture but how the area was wired, multi wire branch circuits have this problem with GFCI'S or a true fault someplace. With the lamp removed will the GFCI still trip when the switch is turned on?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a box for incandescent/CFL lighting that is not rated for insulation contact (IC).

It might not be easy/cheap to replace it. Even if it's a socket you might find it hard to find a replacement part. You will need to pay with either time (DIY) or money to fix it. I doubt contractors will be interested in repair of such a thing, too time-consuming for them and you are unwilling to pay "too much money". Where I live an electrician visits starts from $200

For the same money consider hiring a handyman to do remove the box, add some framing to support a new drywall patch, patch the seam, match-paint, paint the ceiling, cut a round hole and install an IC rated can like this.
[[image]
That would probably also cost you about $200

Comment: I would prefer to remove it all together and update  with a newer light fixture. If it's simple to remove then I can do that myself. I've replaced and patched part of a ceiling before. I'm new to handling wiring all by myself. I just installed a new ceiling fan and wall switch for it. If it's as simple as that then I can handle all that on my own. I was trying to google ways of removing this particular light but not getting any results for it. Definitely want to avoid $200 plus out of pocket.